# Why does this script work in Firefox but not in IE9?

Tags: php, firefox, internet-explorer-9

```
$URL="http://www.villagestone.co.za/mailsendfail.html";
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;$URL\">";
```

Comment: Is that your whole script? What do you want it to do?

Comment: rewrite your code into pure HTML, test it, and if the problem persists, post your question under proper tags. PHP has nothing to do with browsers.

Comment: Very low quality question. Describe the words "does not work" (your expected result and how it behaves). What is the HTML output php generates? Where do you put this <meta> tag?

Answer (score 2):

Ah now I see. Try this:

```
$URL = "http://www.villagestone.co.za/mailsendfail.html";
print "<meta http-equiv=\"refresh\" content=\"1;URL=$URL\">";
```

IE expects the 'URL=' prefix which is why it works in Firefox and not IE.

Answer (score 0):

You're better off redirecting via the `header` function

```
header('Location: '.$URL);
```

Note: This line must appear before any text is output.

Read More: http://php.about.com/od/learnphp/ht/phpredirection.htm

Answer (score 0):

If you have clean string you better use '' like:

```
$URL = 'http://www.villagestone.co.za/mailsendfail.html';
print '<meta http-equiv="refresh" content="1;url=' . $URL . '">';
```